# Joomla upgrade error version 3.5.1 to 3.6.1

Tags: joomla, upgrade

I am facing this error during upgrade:

Error : 1242
Subquery returns more than 1 row SQL=INSERT INTO `#__update_sites_extensions` (`update_site_id`, `extension_id`) VALUES ((SELECT `update_site_id` FROM `#__update_sites` WHERE `name` = 'Joomla! Update Component Update Site'), (SELECT `extension_id` FROM `#__extensions` WHERE `name` = 'com_joomlaupdate'));

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

After updating:

- Go to Extension > Manage > Database.
- Click "Fix".

Answer (score 0):

Login to `phpMyAdmin`, and then click on the `#__extensions` table, and delete the first entry (the one with the lowest ID) that has the following name: "Joomla! Update Component Update Site" (only do that if you have 2 entries). Do the same for the entry where the name is "com_joomlaupdate".

Comment: First of all thank you for the reply, I had removed the mentioned line. When I try to access my website contact page(default module). It shows this error "Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /home/....../plugins/content/pagenavigationtitles/pagenavigationtitles.php on line 30"